Python - PIL.save() issue - The fill character must be a unicode character, not bytes
I have some interesting issue with saving Image via PIL library.
Aim:
to change metadata like "Date Taken", "Creation Date" to pictures from picture name (name is standardize by this format "YYYYMMDD_hhmmdd")
Issue:
the code works well for one picture and causing issue for another picture "The fill character must be a unicode character, not bytes"
Picture1: "20190803_212800.jpeg" --> no issue
Picture2: "20190805_120100.jpeg" --> issue
Code:
import os
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image

Date_dt_Format = "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S"
Name_format = "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"

def Change_Property_picture(File_Name_dt: datetime, file_path: str):
    # read the image data using PIL
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    DateTime_import = File_Name_dt.strftime(Date_dt_Format)

    # extract EXIF data
    exif1 = image.getexif()

    # Update TAGs (34665 --> Exif)
    exif1.get_ifd(34665)[306] = DateTime_import
    exif1.get_ifd(34665)[36867] = DateTime_import
    exif1.get_ifd(34665)[36868] = DateTime_import
    exif1.get_ifd(34665)[50971] = DateTime_import

    creation_time = File_Name_dt.timestamp()
    modification_time = File_Name_dt.timestamp()
    
    # Save
    image.save(fp=f"{file_path}", exif=exif1)
    os.utime(file_path, (creation_time, modification_time))

picture_path = "path to picture"
Pict1_dt = datetime.strptime("20190803_212800", Name_format)
Pict2_dt = datetime.strptime("20190805_120100", Name_format)
Change_Property_picture(File_Name_dt=Pict1_dt ,file_path=f"{picture_path}20190803_212800.jpeg")
Change_Property_picture(File_Name_dt=Pict2_dt ,file_path=f"{picture_path}20190805_120100.jpeg")

Link to download pictures (please download them to your PC): https://1drv.ms/f/s!AgoY0SQPR2-7hJE652WULAxnBjR7pw?e=qrv4hG
Im trying to update picture "Data Taken" parameter mainly and save picture file.
Update1:

Found the source of issue, but still dont know how to correct it:
problem is in GPS infromation where first(correct picture) has it in binary and second dont:
first:


second:


Please show the traceback to the error you're getting too.

By the way, note that this is likely not a lossless conversion (though I could be mistaken and PIL might be smarter than I think).

I suspect you'd do better to use exiftool to do this as it will not decompress and recompress your image and potentially cause quality loss. It's also simpler and faster.

thank you, I will try the exiftool, but I'm really interested why I always have this issue with second Picture. Thank you
